# Scaling JPGs down with PIL results in filesizes larger than the original. I seem to be missing something fundamental

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I just noticed that when I resize a jpg(it may be the same for other encodings, but i've only tried with jpgs), the file size is larger than its source.

For example, an image that is 3762x2840 has a filesize of 513.1KB.  After it is shrunk to 1920x1265 the filesize is 519.9KB.  There's nothing special about the code im using, but here it is:

```
new_image = image.resize(
    (new_width, int(height * scaling_factor)),
    Image.ANTIALIAS)

try:
    new_image.save(
        new_path,
        encoding,
        quality=85,
        optimize=True)
except.......
```

Is the downsampling ratio too large in this case?

Comment: quality factor. the original may have been saved with a much lower quality setting, meaning you'll produce a larger file even though you've cut the number of pixels by a huge amount.

Comment: thanks.  I was thinking `quality` would be with respect to the current quality.

Comment: Some programs have a default quality of 60%

Comment: what do you mean "some programs?"